# Order Records by Specific Order with Specific Row Values

Tags: mysql, sql

```
  Name     | Faction     |   Score
----------------------------------------
  Alpha    | Viva        |   7000
  Beta     | Rico        |   8000
  Bravo    | Morgan      |   9000
  Active   | Rico        |   10000
  Delta    | Edison      |   11000
  Siphon   | Viva        |   12000
  Taximus  | More        |   13000
  Ariticus | Viva        |   14000
  Ariticus | Havoc       |   15000
```

From this table, I'm trying to order the data by specific `Faction`s first, Then continue by `Score DESC` like the following **[all of them are `type=all`]**

`SELECT Name, Score 
FROM memebers 
WHERE type = all 
GROUP BY id 
ORDER BY Faction = 'Viva' DESC, Faction = 'Rico' DESC, Score DESC`

What i expect to get is

```
  Name     | Faction     |   Score
----------------------------------------
  Ariticus | Viva        |   14000
  Siphon   | Viva        |   12000
  Alpha    | Viva        |   7000
  Active   | Rico        |   10000
  Beta     | Rico        |   8000
  Ariticus | Havoc       |   15000
  Taximus  | More        |   13000
  Bravo    | Morgan      |   9000
```

But i keep getting them ordered by `Score DESC` only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `case` expression.

```
ORDER BY case when Faction = 'Viva' then 1
              when Faction = 'Rico' then 2
         else 3 end,
Score DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

For mysql, you can also try `ORDER BY FIELD()` if the Faction value list is small and can be provided in the arguments as given below:

```
SELECT Name, Score 
FROM memebers 
WHERE type = all 
GROUP BY id 
ORDER BY FIELD(Faction, 'Viva', 'Rico', 'Havoc', 'More','Morgan'), Score DESC;
```

Comment: It works, But some faction names are made of Number only like `1412` which doesn't goes well with the function